How to properly connect with Python/PyQt6 to a MariaDB run within a xampp installation?
As a rookie to PyQt/Python I'm trying to learn the basics by just by running simple code examples e.g. from tutorials and modifying them to learn how they work.
But with "connection to databases" I couldn't make any progress so far.
I wrote this simple code (slightly modified from tutorials and forum answers):
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase


def connect_db():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setDatabaseName("test-db")
    db.setUserName("testuser")
    db.setPassword("")
    db.open()

    if not db.isOpen():
        print('Failed!')
        sys.exit(1)

    print('Success!')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        button = QPushButton("Connect to DB")
        button.clicked.connect(connect_db)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


There seems to be no error in the code, but it won't connect to the DB. The settings to access the DB were ok, since I can connect to it with phpmyadmin.
I'm using Python 3.12.5/PyQt 6.6.1 on Windows 10 Home 22H2, and PyCharm 2024.1 Community Edition.
The database server is part of a xampp installation (Version 8.2.0).
I'd rather prefer to use this database server instead of installing a separate one, as has been suggested repeatedly to similar questions.
In some forum posts I googled, it was mentioned that probably a qsqlmysql.dll (or similar for MariaDB) was missing. It was suggested to download the proper version and install it.
If that would be the solution, I immediately face the questions: Where to get the .dll file? What is the proper version? How to install a .dll file? If just copied: to which directory?
Issues that might be obvious to an expert, but not to a learner like me.
Another website suggested to install the "MYSQL Connector", but as far as I understood, this is installed as an option along with the main MYSQL server software. However, during my xampp installion, there was no such option. Do I probably have to manually edit the my.ini?
I tried to tinker with the suggested solution here, but it wouldn't work (seems to be for Linux only?). Already "import MYSQLdb" was not possible. (And yes, the MariaDB server is running.)
Other suggested solutions don't seem to refer to the use of PyQt.
BTW, I wrote a similar code in PHP/HTML, which connects easily to my DB.

you should be able to connect to the same db server.  No reason to spin up a new one.
So, what makes you think it's not working?  You aren't getting failed right?  Are you getting success?  What behavior are you observing?

In fact, I get "failed". What confuses me is, that PyCharm detects no error in the code, not even after it ran. I just can't establish the DB connection. I suspect, I'm missing something, probably a driver, or so...

Reading about QSqlDatabase.open, it seems that "Returns true on success; otherwise returns false . Error information can be retrieved using lastError() ."  So you should call that in your code if the db open returns false (no need for isOpen imho) and then output the error you get so you can debug.

Probably I'm too naive or just act stupidly, but when I insert QSqlDatabase.open() into my code, just after the db.open() line, I get the Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) message from PyCharm. The same happens with QSqlDatabase.lastError(). I also tried to replace the db.open() line by QSqlDatabase.open(), but with the same result. The process seems to terminate even before reaching the  if not... line.
BTW, the site you linked refers to PySide2 and Qt 5.15.11. Does the information there also applies to PyQt6/Qt 6.6.1?

XAMPP replaced mysql with mariadb years ago. No, the two are not the same.

@Shadow Thanks for this hint. I understand that, but as stated here they behave quite similar, and therefore their Qt driver plugins have been merged to "QMYSQL". Do you suggest to change the line db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")?

MariaDB forked from mysql over 15 years ago. Mariadb has released its own connectors that you can download from https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/python-connector I do not know QT, so cannot help you with connecting to mariadb instead of mysql.

db is an instance of QSqlDatabase. When you're calling db.open(), you're calling QSqlDatabase.open.  So that's why I liked to that doc in my comment.
As an instance of QSqlDatabase, db should also have a lastError()  method.  If you add that to your error message, it will probably make it clear why your database connection is not successful.
I'm suggesting something like this:
def connect_db():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setDatabaseName("test-db")
    db.setUserName("testuser")
    db.setPassword("")

    if not db.open():
        print("DB Open Failed:", db.lastError())
        sys.exit(1)

    print('Success!')


Thanks a lot for the patience you are having with me ;-)  The return is now: DB Open Failed: <PyQt6.QtSql.QSqlError object at 0x0000016FAA944750>. Does that mean anything to you?

lastError returns a QSqlError.  Do some exploring... looks like print("DB Open Failed:", db.lastError().text()) might give you some thing interesting

db.lastError().text() returns "Driver not loaded". Therefore I installed the MariaDB Connector via pip install. Now I can use "import mariadb" and "conn = mariadb.connect(...)". I already suspected that it might be something like this. But that's without QtSql, and it still doesn't work with "QSqlDatabase.addDatabase". Some detail is still missing...
I know, that it is not appreciated in stackoverflow to ask additional questions. Should I rather open a new question on how to achieve the same result using QSqlDatabase functions?

Yes, I'd recommend asking a new question about how to load the driver for Qt

@user26841571 Also consider the static functions of QSqlDatabase (specifically, drivers() and isDriverAvailable()). Always check the documentation, and run the code in a terminal or prompt, as IDEs are not always able to show the full traceback or library errors directly sent to stderr.

@musicamante I ran the code from the windows command prompt, having set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1. The driver is found but can't be loaded for some reason. Maybe something with the deps of qsqlmysql.dll is wrong, either the version or the location. I'll try to find out...

@user26841571 It seems doubtful that installing the db connector via pip will help, since that is specific to Python. Qt is written in C/C++, so you need to install the MariaDB C Connector for Windows - see also this SO question, which is very closely related to yours. (PS: contrary to the comment above, it's not advisable to start a new question, as it seems likely your current question is already a duplicate).

@ekhumoro Guess you're right, but in my installation everything seems to look very much different. E.g., the installation directories mentioned in many answers in the SO question don't even exist on my computer. I don't have C:\MYSQL... or C:\Qt... or C:\Program Files\MYSQL... directories. The Qt6 installation is nested deep in the Python directory, MYSQL is stashed in the xampp installation. The subdirectories are different to those mentioned in the SO question and in many other tutorials I already studied. I'm afraid to mess my installations up by doing "trial and error".

@user26841571 It shouldn't make much difference - it just means the equivalent locations have a different root path. Once you've installed the connector, you can copy its libmysql.dll to the relevant Qt bin directory (see the question I linked to above for some hints about how to do this).
